# Android support libraries missing all classes

Tags: gradle, android-support-library

Ever since I updated to support libraries 28.0.0 from 25.x, all the support classes and folders are missing. Specifically, `android.support.v4.app` and `com.google.android.gms.maps.*`

I am properly importing

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
```

My top level build.gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I am using gradle `4.10.3`

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Doing restart with Invalidate Caches did it.